# sorting a dataframe by values and storing index and columns

Tags: sorting, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a pandas DataFrame which is actually a matrix. It looks as shown below

```
    a   b   c
d   1   0   5
e   0   6   2
f   2   0   3
```

I need the values to be sorted and need the values of index and columns of them. the result should be

```
index Column Value

e       b      6

d       c      5

f       c      3
```

Comment: So you want the maximum value from each row, along with it's row name ("index") and column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().nlargest(3).rename_axis(['idx','col']).reset_index(name='val')
print (df1)
  idx col  val
0   e   b    6
1   d   c    5
2   f   c    3
```

For `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = df.stack().nlargest(3).to_frame(name='val')
print (df2)
     val
e b    6
d c    5
f c    3
```